# How does Euron travel so fast?

Tags: game-of-thrones

WARNING: Here be spoilers! (for Game of Thrones Season 7 Episodes 2 and 3)

We all know Euron Greyjoy is a little crazy. Those who have read the book know he is also more than a little dangerous (which is starting to come out on the show also).

In Season 7 episode 2

> We see Euron's Iron fleet wreck Yara and Theon's Iron fleet. I assume this happened between Dragonstone and King's landing, but could be mistaken.

After that, in episode 3 we see

> Euron takes the prisoners he caputured to King's Landing. He then sails all the way around the other side of Westeros to Casterly Rock where he destroys the fleet the Unsullied used to get there.

How did he manage to get from one side of Westeros to the other so quickly, assuming as it is portrayed on the show that

> both of the fleets under Dany's command left at the same or similar times.

It seems that he should be days behind. A few explanations could be:
1. The show is misleading for the sake of time.
2. His ships are much faster (perhaps due to design/favourable winds/enhancement).
3. He has a magical method of travelling faster than normal.

Is there any evidence (in either the show or books) for any of these? Perhaps there is not yet enough information to give a concrete answer, but if there are any hints given they would be good to know. Both book and show answers are fine, they may even be different.

I have added a map for a better understanding of the distances between the places mentioned in the question, all the places are in the lower third, two on the east side of Westeros and the other on the west.[image]

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot

Comment: It didn’t actually show either Euron’s fleet at Kings Landing, or Euron with the fleet at Casterly Rock. The fleet could have been under the command of a lieutenant while he was still at KL.

Comment: Who says it had to be a short time. The Iron Islanders are also much better sailors then a bunch of Eunuchs.

Comment: @Darren well, that's a good point... possibly a reason

Comment: @Edlothiad I was under the impression that the ironborn were sailing for the Eunuchs

Comment: The iron born just got rekt by Euron, they say it in S7E3. Also I'm 99% sure the books say the iron born are quicker anyways

Comment: @Edlothiad I was referring to a few ironborn sailors manning the ships that the unsullied were on, not the entire iron fleet under Yara's control.

Comment: I've removed the 'asoiaf' tag as this has nothing to do with the books.

Comment: I have the feeling that all travels are faster than light in the last seasons.

Comment: @Neow: Isn't it much more likely that there are simply unmentioned time gaps? There are plenty of non-travel things that happen in quick succession for the viewer. E.g. I remember seeing multiple small councils in quick succession when Tyrion was Hand of the King. And travel time does often seem to be accounted for: Bran has been considerably absent as he had the longest most boring travels, and Arya was absent from the last episode because she just pulled a U turn to Winterfell, which means a long and relatively boring journey.

Comment: @Flater Of course, most of travels are boring and the show needs ellipses. But to me it looks like teleportation when I remember the first seasons.

Comment: @Neow: Do you mean that the _present_ looks like teleportation, or the _first seasons_? If you mean the present, keep in mind that the first seasons needed a lot of exposition time, which is revealed in casual conversation, which can be shown during travels (hence why travels were more visible to the viewer). In the present, there's more focus on the current actions, which tend to take place at the _destination_ that people travel to, rather than on the road. Different story focus, different location for events.

Comment: @Darren They clearly showed _The Silence_, he would not have given command of his maiden ship to some other commander.

Comment: @Möoz: That is very arguable. Assuming that it was the same fleet who launched both attacks, and given that Euron stopped by King's Landing, it's perfectly possible for Euron's fleet to depart without him and meet up with him later. If Euron's right hand is only seeing to the execution of Euron's orders, then he shouldn't really be considered "some other commander". Everyone has a right hand (e.g. the Hand of the King, Davos, Jorah, Podrick, ...), there is currently no reason (in the show) to believe that Euron is different in this regard. It's an entire culture of vassalization.

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/why-did-the-unsullied-travel-by-sea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a few gaps in your assumptions that can give Euron a window to do what he does.

Note that I'm forgoing spoiler tags as this entire answer is one big spoiler.

> We see Euron's Iron fleet wreck Yara and Theon's Iron fleet. I assume this happened **between Dragonstone and King's landing**, but could be mistaken.

Looking at the map you posted, there's no reason for Yara to sail towards King's Landing (Blackwater Bay in general).
*Although this is an assumption on my part, the fact that the Sand Snakes were cozy in their hammocks and Yara was having a drink with Ellaria, it stands to reason that they had been travelling some time. So I doubt that the ambush took place near Blackwater Bay.*

However, looking at the route from Dragonstone to **Sunspear** (their intended destination), it seems there are a few locations that are hard to avoid. Keep in mind that it's significantly easier to sail by staying close to shore (visual aid), rather than having to rely on compasses or astronomy.

Euron could have been waiting for them at one of the unavoidable points, e.g. the entrance to the sea of Dorne, or the eastern cape just south of the sea of Dorne. Any route that avoid these points will be incredibly convoluted, and it seems clear that Yara wasn't expecting hostile interaction on the way (so it makes no sense for her to take such a convoluted route then)

> How did he manage to get from one side of Westeros to the other so quickly, assuming as it is portrayed on the show that both of the fleets under Dany's command left at the same or similar times.

It would be more accurate to say that Grey Worm and Yara's fleets started **preparing** for their journey at the same time.
Looking at the map once again, if Yara and Grey Worm left at the same time, they must have been travelling together, since Sunspear is on the way to Casterly Rock.

Yara's mission was to **fetch** Dornish soldiers. Logically, she must have left with relatively empty ships, so that the Dornish can be added (without needing to leave others behind, which would defeat the purpose). That requires little preparation time.

Grey Worm's mission was to **send** soldiers. This means that a lot more preparation time is needed. Provisioning the boats, loading the men, ...

It also seems fair to consider that the Greyjoys are the most adept sailors compared to everyone else, so it's very likely that they can mobilize faster than others. This can apply to both **Yara and Euron**.

---

### New conclusions

Let me rewrite your interpretation according to the differences I've addressed.

- Yara leaves before Grey Worm, due to less preparation time and having worthy sailors as a crew.
- Euron waits for Yara at given location and ambushes her.
- Euron sends his fleet to Casterly Rock (he himself took a trip to King's Landing if you remember)

There are two options here:

- Euron's fleet could have left for Casterly Rock before Grey Worm. This makes it likely that they were again waiting to ambush Grey Worm, and were even there before him.
- Maybe Grey Worm had already progressed further when Euron's fleet departed for the Rock, but since Euron ambushed Yara somewhere between Dragonstone and Sunspear (which is en route to Casterly Rock), then Euron's fleet had less distance to travel than Grey Worm did. If you combine the Greyjoy sailing aptitude, shorter travel distance, and Grey Worm's time needed to take Casterly Rock after their sailing trip; then this should give Euron's fleet more than enough time to catch up.

Regardless of the options, I think the relatively unmentioned but important preparation time for Grey Worm's fleet to depart gave Euron enough time to attack both fleets.

Answer (score 8):

I thought of the same thing today and here is what I came up with:

Euron talks with Cersei in Kings Landing. Then he sails to the location between Dragonstone and Sunspear where he ambushes the Sand Snakes in episode 2. Kings Landing is between Dragonstone and Sunspear, so with his fast ships he can easily ambush them.

In episode 3 he brings his fleet to Kings Landing, which is also possible. It's just a return trip. **Now the important part begins:**

In episode 3 Tyrion says that Euron might have fleets in multiple locations, when Daenerys suggests trying to fight them with dragons. That is the **foreshadowing**. After that the attack begins in Casterly Rock. We also see again from the map that Pyke is relatively close to Casterly Rock, so the Ironborn can make a second fleet and send it to Casterly Rock before the Unsullied arrive.

I accept that the last ship at the end of the battle looks like "Silence" but we don't see Euron Greyjoy anywhere in the scene. He is the rockstar of the show for now, so if he was there we would probably see him. He is sort of like a **deux ex machina** for House Lannister in this season.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most obvious answer is that it just does not make sense and you've come to that conclusion - it's simply a plot hole.

The geography in the show at this point does not make sense at all and some things just happen out of convenience, they have not thought of everything. After all, if showing dragons, magic and undead on screen is believable then surely the people will believe that the characters could've traveled from point A to point B in the needed amount of time.

I like your proposed explanation, as well as atayenel's, and I'd like to add that Euron might of sent his fleet to Casterly Rock while heading to Kings Landing so he isn't actually there and all these theories would make sense, however they were never implied in the show, which is why for now I would dismiss them. They can't be ruled out for future episodes but it seems unlikely that they will come back to this.

In terms of books, Euron is nowhere near this stage as far as I know (I have not read the books). Euron has yet to travel to Kings Landing even once or form a fleet in the books.

Comment: " if showing dragons,magic and undead on screen is believable then surely the people will believe that the characters could've traveled from point A to point B in the needed amount of time" The use of magic does not preclude common sense. You can't point to magic are the catch-all reason to explain plot holes that aren't even related to magic (unless show Euron is as magically inclined as book Euron, but that hasn't been part of the show OR your answer)

Comment: I realise that, it was just sarcasm on my end implying that the show runners feel that it's not necessary to have common sense when they're doing fiction which is obviously not true and I too am not happy with it and I never meant to explain the plot holes with magic. Other answers  offer this as a solution as Euron in the books has magical powers but as I mentioned in my original reply that  dismiss all the other proclaimed explanations (including this) as non of them make sense as they were never explained in the show. Unless something changes in upcoming episodes, this is simply a plot hole