# Population of Iron Islands?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We know that Iron Islands has a huge navy. It is their main strength. We also know that Iron Islands are barren land, very small and even if they fish extensively, it should not support a population as great as the North. In fact, it was one of their motives when they waged war against the North, to obtain *Lebensraum* for their people.

I am not really shocked with their ship building efficiency. They might steal the wood easily from many unprotected forests in the North or in the Riverlands. The Iron Fleet should already have around 500 ships in total. Building 500 more in one or two years for a seafarer nation should not be the greatest challenge.

However, for such a small nation to man even 500 ships efficiently puzzles me. In a world where the North can muster 20000 men (if they took their time it would at most be 40000), how did Iron Islands man 1000 ships? What would be the crew per ship?

One of the best comparisons I could find is the [taking of Deepwood Motte](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Taking_of_Deepwood_Motte), where Asha Greyjoy commaned 30 longships and about 1000 men, making it about 30 men per ship. [Battle for Deepwood Motte](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fight_by_Deepwood_Motte) is another possible reference point, where it is claimed that Asha Greyjoy had 4 longships and 200 men. This makes 50 men per longship.

So, how can Iron Islands support a fighting population of 30000 while the best North can do is 40000?

Book answers are preferred but TV show answers are also welcome.

Comment: One thing to note: North has always been sparsely populated so they shouldn't be taken as a benchmark for manpower. Iron Islands have fallen into poverty after the conquest, that was not the case before the conquest when the Ironborn conquered rich lands like Riverlands and looted whatever resources they needed to sustain a high population

Comment: If you want to compare manpower, compare Iron Islands to Westerlands or The Reach. Not the North which is also very sparsely populated, and outsiders tend to avoid immigrating to the North, so much so that Eddard Stark thought that even the Promise of lands wouldn't be able to attract people to settle New Gift in face of a coming cruel Northern winter

Comment: Out-of-universe: GRRM may just have 1000 ships because it sounds cool (and has a nice resonance with the Trojan War). The Iron Islands are clearly based on the Vikings of early medieval Europe, and not any larger than Norway/Sweden/Denmark in our world. The Viking army which conquered most of England in 865 CE was considered large for its time, and is [estimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Heathen_Army) at no more than a few thousand. So the Iron Islands fleet is about 10 times bigger than a "realistic" size.

Comment: @Aegon Sparsely populated does not mean "small population". The North's population could be massive, but since it's the size of the other 6 kingdoms combined it's "sparsely populated".

Comment: You've got a lot of questions here. Asking 1. How many people are there? 2. How they provide for their population? 3. How did they man 1000 ships? 4. How many men was there to a ship? That's a lot of sub questions with a very broad scope for you answer, Maybe you could consider narrowing your question slightly

Comment: @Edlothiad Yes that is the tricky bit. The canon used the word "Sparsely Populated" so that's what I am sticking with as well however all other Indicators show Northern Population is very low e.g. Robert commenting that he saw very low population from the Neck upwards, Robb managing to gather only 20000 swords for WotFK (Although it wasn't the entire strength of North, But they were the most eligible men to be found as per Rodrik Cassel). But then again, we can attribute both of these things to low population density and huge area

Comment: Related on M&TV: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55865/how-many-ironborn-are-there/55869#55869

Comment: @Edlothiad Actually 2 is not a part of my question at all. The answer is fishing obviously. 3 and 4 are my approach to find the population of iron islands, anyone can feel free to use another approach. The whole question is devoted to addressing a possible illogical point in both the books ans series.

Comment: `Building 500 more in one or two years for a seafarer nation should not be the greatest challenge. However, for such a small nation to man even 500 ships efficiently puzzles me.` It takes WAY more manpower and resources to build a ship than to man a ship. To compare shipbuilding costs, look at the US Cyclone class patrol boat. It is very small and cheap, as far a navel vessels go. It costs $20 Million (the newer ships replacing it cost 500-800 million) and it has a crew of 30. You could crew it for a decade for its construction cost.

Comment: And our ship building is more efficient than in the middle ages, while we pay out sailors more than what iron island conscripts would receive.

Comment: @Shane Rome built 120 war ships in 1 year (261 BC) without ever having built one, just by copying a shipwrecked ship. Population by that time was under 500,000. I assume a sea-based civilization would go way further than that. Also, comparing hi-tech and modern wages with wood, slaves and crews fighting for bounty is not a very good measure

Comment: according to this nice (yet speculative) work https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/1la8my/spoilers_all_speculative_westeros_demographic_maps/ , Iron Islands had around half a million people. Building a 50k army wouldn't be an issue for people in which both men and women are warriors and their subsistence depends mainly on raiding and looting

Comment: @Devin, I'm not sure why you brought up those numbers, but going off them, they don't address whether or not building a ship takes more resources than crewing it does. That said, going off those numbers, to build five times as many ships would take *at least* 5 times as many people. That's ignoring the fact that doing 5 times more of something is more than just 5 times more difficult. And ignoring the fact that cutting down your own trees and building a boat is **A LOT** easier than looting trees, dragging them home, then building a boat.

Comment: And I admit that it isn't a very good measure. But the direction of the error makes my point stronger. Our ships are built efficiently with people operating machines. Our shipwrights are paid well enough, they aren't slaves. This means that the Islands needs more builders per boat.

Comment: Maybe I failed to explain my point: what I mean is that history shows this is a plausible figure for a sea civilization that builds ships (and don't forget: STEALS ships). Comparing it to modern production systems is not an accurate measure, because you have machines, workers, different companies, wages, buildings and so on. Building a ship out of wood by slaves or people driven by their need to loot is way cheaper (and again: don't forget STEALING). Besides, I think the quote is about the number of people, not the COST of that people (hence my comment on number of ships over population)

Comment: @Shane I am sorry but your approach is wrong. Today's engineering is usually less efficient than medieval ages. The medieval factor are already described by Devin, but there is also an engineering approach change. Today any manufactured device go through a series of tests, stress tests, endurance tests, one-component fail safe measures etc etc. With combat equipment this is even more obvious. Not only you have to make sure your vehicle does what it is supposed to do, you also have to make sure all individual components are safe and do not couple with each other, i.e., causing malfunction in...

Comment: @Shane ... other components. I think the last time someone produced things without caring their quality was Soviets producing 35000 T34s. They were basic and efficient designs and fared well compared to the over-engineered German tanks, simply thanks to their superior numbers. This was the norm in medieval engineering. I wouldn't expect Euron's shipbuilders perfecting design of each ship. Rather, they were probably copying things that worked well in the previous designs and avoiding things that were not efficient.

Comment: `Maybe I failed to explain my point: what I mean is that history shows this is a plausible figure for a sea civilization that builds ships` Plausible for a civ that is **significantly** larger than the romans you describe were. So *completely and absolutely implausible* for the Islands. A population half the size isn't going to build five times as many ships. But all of that is besides the point. All I'm really saying is that it takes far more resources and men to build ships than man ships. Do you disagree?

Comment: @C.Koca Our ability to move ship building materials to where they need to be dwarfs all of that. On the cheap side, to build a modern ship costs what it takes to crew it for a decade. Let's say you are right about the relative resources that go into building olden ships. So it only costs what it takes to crew it for half a decade. Or 2-3 years. That's still *drastically* more resources going in to ship building than ship operating. That's my whole point. Do you disagree?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The true answer is we do not know the exact size of the Iron Islands population and so it seems appropriate to use @Aegon's image here:

[image: We do not <s>sow<s> know]

However, the [awoiaf page on the Iron Islands](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Iron_Islands) cites that they have 20,000 men and 500 longships which in turn is cited from "A Game of Thrones: d20-based Open Gaming RPG." which is a semi-canon source.

We can also get a figure of 15,000 fighting men from [this post on atlasoficeandfireblog](https://atlasoficeandfireblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/06/the-population-of-the-seven-kingdoms/) which is cited from this video by Elio Garcia:

From there the article extrapolates that the Iron Islands has a population of 1.5 million but that is using a basis that the fighters make up 1% of the population which seems low for a nation such as the Ironborn. Using a figure more around 10% we get 150,000 which seems more reasonable. This isn't exactly unfeasible as in WWII many nations managed to get around 10% fighting population although it isn't sustainable but these are times of war for Westeros.

So using both figures for fighting men and a rough estimate of between 1-10% of the population being fighters we get a population between 150,000 and 2,000,000 though it seems likely to be on the lower side of things.

However, in my opinion (especially as they rely on raiding), the percentage of fighting men is likely around 3-5% maybe a bit higher which gives a total population of between 450,000 and 1,000,000.

Comment: Your article is interesting, you got a +1 for it. But I'm afraid that the numbers are totally wrong. According to canon, North has less than 1 million people. And Dorne is the least populous of the Big Houses.   Moreover you can't extrapolate a percentage of fighters from modern armies with expensive weapons, and logistics. We are speaking of middle ages armies. They feed on the lands and they have to be disbanded to harvest.   For the Iron men it is even more wrong. They are inspired from Vikings. Most men would be mobilised for raids/plunders.

Comment: Moreover, Targaryens would not have been able to maintain their power with such a weak fiefdom (relative to the other described).

Comment: Of interest is that a fisherman is a useful skilled sailor, while a farmer isn't a skilled footman: the art of gathering food on the sea is closer to warcraft than tilling the soil.  And all of the crew on a ship need not be warriors; they can be sailors or even galley-slaves.  Finally, you could imagine calling up non-warships (like fishing craft) to keep your warships fed while you cross the world, provide supply capacity, and the like.

Comment: Off topic: your avatar made me double-take.  Hats for the hatless.  ;)

Comment: @xrorox It is a range extrapolated from other works using educated guesses. If I was confident on the numbers I would said an absolute one not a range. Can you point me to this figure for the northern population?

Comment: @Wildcard Well it is better than a plain old Gravatar...

Comment: I believed it was book cannon when I read it, but I cannot find my source back. And numbers don't add up with the book canon population of king's Landings (500 000).  However, it is series canon : http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_North#cite_note-0.

Comment: @xrorox If you read further the numbers don't add up again. Tyrion states the population of KL is 1 million yet Jaime has stated before it is 0.5 million and Tyrion has been away so has no way of knowing. Also the 3-4 million estimate for the North was given by Elio Garcia a co-author to The World of Ice and Fire which your source also states. Note that the wikia you link is generally not considered too good of a source as anyone can edit it though in this case it does have backing from the show.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot   There is a controversy on that numbers that seemed to be made up by the show runners.     One of the main explanation for the 1 million number is war refugees.    The 500K number is also well discussed. Actually, Baelish established a special tax in order to roughly estimate the number of people actually living at Port Real.   I don't know where and when Tyrion got his numbers. The 1 million may have been true before he fled from Westeros.

Comment: @xrorox The 1 million may well have been speculation of extra war refugees from the 500k before he fled but he's only guessing. I think it's safe to say the shows numbers are inaccurate.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot  Numbers in a fantasy world are pure speculation anyway. For the  7 Kingdoms it is also completely unsafe to estimate population based on military forces.   According to Wikipedia, in emergency case and for short duration the Roman Empire would be able to mobilise "as much as 10% (210s BCE) of total Roman population (which included as many as 75% of males aged 17–45)"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobilization.   Winter may kill most old people, especially in the North. Iron men may have many wives. Westeros is not Europe. So any number may feel good. Only George can answer.

Comment: @xrorox Hence why I gave a range...

Answer (score 2):

Asha Greyjoy did some raids. While raiding you need additionnal warriors.
You may have some heavy losses on land, and you need people to bring the ships back.

Euron is going to do naval warfare, so you need far less infantry. 
Presuming that ship boarding is not the main way to fight.

There is a main difference between the North and iron islands.
It is a feeding and economic one, you need far less fishermen to feed everyone than you need farmers.
And the North climate is harsh.

So the North need far far more people in order to raise an army of equivalent size.

And the iron islands are not that small. They are almost no farming lands, few forests. The islands are likely crowded.

Do not forget this is war on Westeros. You can kill and plunder for the Crown. You have few economic activities to do on the iron islands.
There is war/raiding, fishing and mining.

So you may consider the iron men as a people in arms. 
In reality, you got nomadic people which were in such a situation.
One major defeat, and they could disapear.

That's why nomads including mongols were able to conquer China or be a major threat whereas China was vastly more populated.

We do not know the Iron island population. But in such a context they may be able to raise 20 000 soldiers from a 60 000 population. War will pay for itself.

These numbers do not consider women that may be part of raids. 
The iron men are inspired from vikings, which had shield maiden. 
And we have on example of a warrior woman in Yara/Asha, and she did not seem to be ill considered because of it.
Maybe they have a small percentage of able bodied women that fight with the men.

Update :

Their population may be far greater in number. They have huge fishing ground. Very few northmen actually live on the west coast.
The main problems would be social unrest due to lack of space, and economic activities.

The 60 000 people seem (to me) the minimum population to raise such an army. 
You still keep small garrison, some fishermen, some miners.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion of 60,000? And why do you come to that number if right before it you say "We do not know the Iron island population."

Comment: I said we do not know their minimal population because there is no official source to my knowledge.  Iron men are almost a people in arms, so they may be able to raise most of the able bodied men.  But you have to exclude the old, the children, keep a small garrison and some fishermen. Then double it, in order to take women into accounts.   So 60 000, seems to be the bare minimum.

Comment: I understand that but you don't seem to have any justification to those numbers, it feels like you've just plucked them out of the air because they feel right.

Comment: It is a wild guess. We can't came with a good numbers withouth knowing number of children per family, ect. If we consider Euron way of thinking, it is unlikely they could mobilise more men. And we may suppose that their population is quite young, because the iron islands were ransacked when Theon was a child.  They do not require much logistics it is not the Iron way.   So depending on the number of women and children you may have more people. But we do not have much information about them. Moreover, the North is less than a million people. So I'm inclined to take the smallest possible number.

Comment: “Maybe they have a small percentage of able bodied women that fight with the men.” Maybe it’s not so small.

Comment: If it's a wild guess what's the point in posting it? You have no idea so why post it like it is fact?

Comment: The post owner did not ask the exact population of the Iron Islands. He asked how they could raise such an army relatively to the North.  Ironmen are inspired from vikings and we do know things about vikings. 60000 should be a close numbers for vikings in our reality. In Westeros, it is hard to say. In middle ages no cities could match Kings landings because of massive illness.  Unrelated, I cannot comment your post, but your article  estimate 4 million people for the North whereas cannon sources say less than 1 million : http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_North

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding the number of people:**

According to a [semi-canon source](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Iron_Islands) the isles can raise approximately **twenty thousand men**.

Granted this would be *fighting men*. So it depends how much a total population would we to be able to raise 20,000. If we look at the United States, the total active and reserve military is roughly 1.5 million currently, but [peaked during WWII](http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0004598.html) at 12 million. In 1945 the population was around 139 million. So this gives roughly 10% of the population.

Using this number, which I feel is conservative, gives **a population of 200,000 for the Iron Islands.**

---

**Regarding the number of ships:**

[So Spake Martin:](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Re_Greyjoy_Fleet)

> In brief, though... **the Iron Islands can float a lot more than a hundred ships**. Each of the major lords probably commands that any.
>
> However, it is important to remember that the longships are smaller and simpler than the fleets that Joffrey and Stannis warred with on the Blackwater. The former are Viking longboats, more or less; for the latter, think Venetian/Byzantine dromonds of war.

---

**Extrapolation**

Theon's ship, the [Sea Bitch](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sea_Bitch),

> was hundred feet long, had a single mast and fifty oars. It has a deck large enough to hold a hundred men and an iron ram.

50 oars = 50 men and I will give leniency to the Sea Bitch and say she was average to large sized for the Iron Fleet.

So even if the 1000 ships Euron wants to build are half the size of the Sea Bitch, **he is mostly likely going to need more men.**